# Leer línea por línea de un archivo de texto en C#

Tags: c#, .net

Necesito leer un archivo `.txt` en C# línea por línea. El problema es que el archivo tiene un encabezado, detalle y sumario. Los datos del encabezado los pasaré a un `Label` o `TextBox`, los del detalle irán a un `DataSet` para distribuirse en un `DataGridView` y los del sumario también irían al `TextBox`.

El problema es que no encuentro pie ni cabeza de cómo sacar las lineas que inician en `E`, `D` o `S` y hacer los campos.

Contenido del archivo:

> E ENV 123456789042003
>   D0261753450260030694200100000000000000000018620000000000000000000954150
>   D0261813060260035815900100000000000000000010000000000000000000000400150
>   D0219262300180063012900100000000000000000005745000000000000000000291650
>   S S000005

Si se dan cuenta, las líneas inician con los nombres de la estructura del archivo de texto, lo que no llego a la conclusión cómo con la clase `StreamReader` pasaría esos datos. Los campos dentro del desarrollo irán separados con coma.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Si pusieras los intentos de lo que has tratado de hacer nos podríamos dar una idea de cómo empezar. Te doy una pista, usa una lista de cadenas `List<string>` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Las lineas las puedes leer usando ReadLine().

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        string linea = sr.ReadLine();
        char tipo = linea.Substring(0, 1); // tipo de estructura
        string datos = linea.Substring(1); // linea sin el tipo de estructura
        switch( tipo ) // Tipo de estructura
        {
            case 'E':
                // Hacer algo con la linea de encabezado
                break;
            case 'D':
                // Hacer algo con la linea de detalle
                break;
            case 'S':
                // Hacer algo con la linea de sumario
                break;
            default:
                // Encontramos una linea con un formato desconocido
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el archivo que intentas abrir y leer contiene pocas líneas podrías utilizar el método ReadAllLines(), por ejemplo:

```
//Abrir el archivo, recuperar filas y cerrar el archivo
string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\SomeDocument.txt", Encoding.Default);

//Recuperar el encabezado
txtHeader.Text = rows[0];

//Crear una instancia de la clase DataTable para contener las líneas de los detalles
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string)); //Establecer los tipos adecuados
dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));

//Recuperar los detalles, por ejemplo línea con 3 datos separados por una coma (,)
//D02617534502600,30694200100000000,18620000000954150
for (int i = 1; i < rows.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["Col1"] = rows[i].Split(',')[0];
    dr["Col2"] = rows[i].Split(',')[1];
    dr["Col3"] = rows[i].Split(',')[2];

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

//Recuperar el resumen
txtSummary.Text = rows[rows.GetLength(0) - 1];
```

Comment: Cómo hago para asignarle una ruta al RealAllLines, y a la vez poder retornar valores en un mismo método.