# Tomar valor retornado de un método, en otro método

Tags: c#, .net

Quisiera tomar el valor retornado por una método que crea un array, y utilizarlo en otro método.

Por ejemplo:

```
     public string[] Metodo(string dir)
    {
        string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(dir);
        return rows;
    }
```

Quisiera usar ese array retornado, en otro método que pueda ser usado con mi botón. Ejemplo:

```
     private void leer(string rnc, string proceso, string fecha)
    {
        //Usar el retorno de mi otro método, para dividirlo y usar sus 
        valores
        string[] encabezado = rows[0].Split(',');
        encabezado[1] = proceso;
        encabezado[2] = rnc;
        encabezado[3] = fecha;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Porqué crear una nueva pregunta y no editar tu anterior pregunta para añadir más detalle? o definir que pregunta debe ser considerada. Por ejemplo, en [Leer línea por línea de un archivo de texto en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103280) se visualiza como es la estructura de tu cadena, pero en ésta pregunta no lo consideras.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Leer línea por línea de un archivo de texto en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103280/leer-l%c3%adnea-por-l%c3%adnea-de-un-archivo-de-texto-en-c)

Comment: No son las mismas preguntas. Esta pregunta podría ser de mucha ayuda a otros usuarios que quieren implementar métodos dentro de métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer el contenido del archivo y generar el encabezado en el metodo `leer()` que tiene como parametro el `dir` y retornas el encabezado:

```
 private string[] leer(string dir, string rnc, string proceso, string fecha)
 {
    string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(dir);
    string a = string.Concat(rows);
    string[] encabezado = rows[0].Split(',');
    encabezado[1] = proceso;
    encabezado[2] = rnc;
    encabezado[3] = fecha;
    return encabezado;
}
```

Comment: Estaría en el mismo problema, cómo implementaría el encabezado en otro método para utilizarlo?

Comment: Pero si ejecutas este metodo, te estaria retornando el encabezado. O me pierdo de algo

Comment: El problema es que no solo quiero sacar el encabezado de ese array. También usaré otros parámetros de las otras líneas del array para descargarlos en un dataset y datagridview.

Comment: Entonces porque no agrupas todo ese funcionamiento en un solo metodo?

Comment: Por que no puedo entrar variables y enviar variables a la vez, o sí? Por ejemplo:

Entrar el valor de dir desde el opendialog que tengo en el formulario, y a la vez enviar el resultado de un array. Podría hacer eso?

Comment: Por ejemplo...?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65862/discussion-between-maicol-lenin-and-einer).

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener únicamente el encabezado, simplemente define un valor de retorno tipo `string[]` y al final del método retorna el valor de encabezado:

```
 private string[] leer(string dir, string rnc, string proceso, string fecha)
 {
    string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(dir);
   // string a = string.Concat(rows);
    string[] encabezado = rows[0].Split(',');
    encabezado[1] = proceso;
    encabezado[2] = rnc;
    encabezado[3] = fecha;
    return encabezado;
}
```

En este caso, para que serviría unicamente obtener el encabezado si estas enviando además la ruta del archivo que contiene los datos.

**Si recibes la ruta del archivo que contiene los datos, puedes obtener los datos y además agregar el encabezado como primer elemento de este array de datos** 
de esta forma:

```
  private string[] leer(string dir, string rnc, string proceso, string fecha)
    {
        //Obtiene datos de archivo.
        string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(dir);

        //Dimensiona array y agrega los datos del encabezado.
        string[] datosencabezado = new string[3];
        datosencabezado[0] = proceso+",";
        datosencabezado[1] = rnc + ",";
        datosencabezado[2] = fecha;
        string[] encabezado = new string[] { string.Concat(datosencabezado) };
        //Copia el encabezado en el primer elemento del array.   
        var resultado = new string[encabezado.Length + rows.Length];
        //Agrega encabezado como primer elemento.
        encabezado.CopyTo(resultado, 0);
        rows.CopyTo(resultado, encabezado.Length);

        //Retorna resultados.
        return resultado;
    }
```